# I have an error when using Firebase with RecyclearView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get those errors when i run my app:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                    Process: com.google.example.adinaranayaragh, PID: 26564
>                                                                                           com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.google.example.adinaranayaragh.MyItem$Sellm does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.example.adinaranayaragh.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getConvertedObject(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:301)
>                                                                                               at com.google.example.adinaranayaragh.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter$1.onChildAdded(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:80)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

My project is available [on Github](https://github.com/mbcdeveloping/customerApp_TradingAdvices).

Here's the firebase database structure:

```json
{
    "items": {
        "it1": {
            "buy": {
                "buyBellow": 19023,
                "date": "7.jan2016",
                "stoploss": 12455,
                "target1": 12548,
                "target2": 12444
            },
            "sell": {
                "date": "7jan",
                "sellAbove": 22000,
                "stoploss": 14522,
                "target1": 21222,
                "target2": 22245
            },
            "title": "Gold"
        },
        "it2": {
            "buy": {
                "buyBellow": 19023,
                "date": "7.jan2016",
                "stoploss": 12455,
                "target1": 12548,
                "target2": 12444
            },
            "sell": {
                "date": "7jan",
                "sellAbove": 22000,
                "stoploss": 14522,
                "target1": 21222,
                "target2": 22245
            },
            "title": "GoldM"
        },
        "it3": {
            "buy": {
                "buyBellow": 19023,
                "date": "7.jan2016",
                "stoploss": 12455,
                "target1": 12548,
                "target2": 12444
            },
            "sell": {
                "date": "7jan",
                "sellAbove": 22000,
                "stoploss": 14522,
                "target1": 21222,
                "target2": 22245
            },
            "title": "Silver"
        },
        "it4": {
            "buy": {
                "buyBellow": 19023,
                "date": "7.jan2016",
                "stoploss": 12455,
                "target1": 12548,
                "target2": 12444
            },
            "sell": {
                "date": "7jan",
                "sellAbove": 22000,
                "stoploss": 14522,
                "target1": 21222,
                "target2": 22245
            },
            "title": "SilverM"
        }
    },
    "news": ""
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make those objects (items) appear in my app in the `RecyclerView`, but I get the above error when I try to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either make Sellm static or declare it in a separate file.

```
public class MyItem {
    ....

    public static class Sellm {
        ....
    }
}
```