# Firebase DatabseError only after app is relesased to google play - android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play

I'm making an app that uses the firebase database. My app was working with no crashes, until I released it as beta on google play. When I released the app it kept crashing and returning a com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException on one line. The exact same code but unreleased does not crash.

Here's the entire stack trace:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzf (Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx (Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbw (Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza (Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(UnknownSource)
```

> ```
>     at aheschl.studyup.NewSet$2.onClick (NewSet.java:129)
> ```

```
    at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6308)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:11202)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23969)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6816)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Here is the code from the onClickListener that the stack trace references(the line with a blockquote is what is triggering the error):

```
CardSet newSetOfWords = new CardSet(name, words);

String id;

id = user.getUid();

DatabaseReference newReference = database.getReference(id + "/" + name);
```

> ```
> newReference.setValue(newSetOfWords);
> ```

```
Intent i = new Intent(NewSet.this, TeacherView.class);

startActivity(i);

finish();
```

I don't know if this could help but here is my database access rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth != null"
   }
 }
```

UPDATE--

Here's the proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in

//This is what I copied off  the guide on the firebase website

# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class aheschl.studyup.** {
  *;
}
```

And here is CardSet:

```
public class CardSet {

    private String name;

    private ArrayList<String> words;

    public CardSet(String name, ArrayList<String> words){
        this.name = name;
        this.words = words;
    }

    protected String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> getWords(){
        return words;
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you configure Proguard as described in the [Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)?  You need to add commands to your `proguard-rules.pro` file to retain model classes.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have it configured before. I just added the commands from the setup guide and will release a new version to see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it still has the same issue after I added the changes from the guide.

Comment: Can you post your `proguard-rules.pro` file contents?  I still think the problem is related to minification and removal of symbols for your `CardSet` class.

Comment: Sure, I will add it in an edit of my post.

Comment: The stack trace you posted contains `DatabaseException`.  Is there no message after it?  For example, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48138673/4815718).

Comment: Try changing `getName()` and `getWords()` in `CardSet` from `protected` to `public`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try that. And no, I copied the entire log from the developers console.

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the getters in CardSet fixed the crash!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POJO getter/setter methods must be `public`:

```
public class CardSet {

    private String name;

    private ArrayList<String> words;

    public CardSet(String name, ArrayList<String> words){
        this.name = name;
        this.words = words;
    }

    public String getName() {  // changed from protected
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWords(){  // changed from protected
        return words;
    }

}
```

And when building for release with `minifyEnabled`, Proguard must be configured to retain POJO classes.  This is described in the [Realtime Database for Android Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/):

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package aheschl.studyup.
-keepclassmembers class aheschl.studyup.** {
  *;
}
```