# App keeps crashing due to Firebase DatabaseException

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My users are getting the following exception after they download my app. Basically the app crashes completely when you try to open it after downloading from play store even on my end, but when I run the app locally the app doesn't crash. please help

the exception :

```
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init> (CustomClassMapper.java:11)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass (CustomClassMapper.java:12)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean (CustomClassMapper.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass (CustomClassMapper.java:4)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass (CustomClassMapper.java:6)
  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue (DataSnapshot.java:6)
  at com.wallpapers_8k_Anime_Lofi.app.Fragments.AnimeFragment$1.onDataChange (AnimeFragment.java:6)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent (ValueEventRegistration.java:2)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire (DataEvent.java:2)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run (EventRaiser.java:6)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7615)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Comment: The most common cause for this is when you didn't configure ProGuard correctly in release builds. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777470/firebase-databseerror-only-after-app-is-relesased-to-google-play-android/48779918#48779918

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This worked thank you